# Using Google's text to speech on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient, text-to-speech, http-status-code-403

I’m writing some code to use Google translate’s text to speech using a simple GET method and I’m perplexed as to why it doesn’t work.  For example, click on…

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello

I wrote some C# code and, from what I can tell, it should work, but it doesn’t.  I wander if Google is blocking the requests?  Trying this from console gives me a 403 Error (“Forbidden”).

Below is the code.  If anyone can help, I’d appreciate it!

```
namespace WCTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string searchString = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello"; 

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)" + " (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            client.Headers["Referrer"] = "http://brillisoft.com"; 

            client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    Stream audio = e.Result;
                    mediaElement1.SetSource(audio);
                    mediaElement1.Play();
                }
            };

            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(searchString));

        }
    }
}
```

Update... March 10th...

The saga continues... The following code works on some of my colleagues' computers, but not on mine... What could cause that?  Please let me know if this works for you and if you think it's necessary to save the file to IsolatedStorage...

```
namespace PhoneApp1 
{ 
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage 
    { 
        // Constructor 
        public MainPage() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 

        string searchString = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=it+works"; 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            WebClient client = new WebClient(); 

            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)" + " (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"; 

            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "http://translate.google.com"; 

            client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, ex) => 
            { 

                if (ex.Error == null) 
                { 
                    using (var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 
                    { 
                        if (store.FileExists("hello3.mp3")) 
                        { 
                            store.DeleteFile("hello3.mp3"); 
                        } 
                        using (var fs = new System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream("hello3.mp3", System.IO.FileMode.Create, store)) 
                        { 
                            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[ex.Result.Length]; 
                            ex.Result.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length); 
                            fs.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length); 
                            fs.Flush(); 

                            mediaElement1.SetSource(fs); 
                        } 
                    } 

                    mediaElement1.Play(); 

                } 

            }; 

            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(searchString)); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does it work from your browser? Does on mine. If you're tryign to spoof the headers then make sure you're setting them all like on the browser.

Comment: Yes, it works from the browser and from the console, if I set a user agent...